# WCF host as windows service

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, networking, service

WCF is hosted in windows service, and netsh is used for creating https binding on portno (eg:8777), Service is running but nestat did not show port 8777 as listening.  Firewall is not blocking the port. API is not reachable. What could be the reason for this? could this be because of the GPO or windows patch? The windows operating system is Windows server 2019.

Same port when created as IIS website is working. We have added rules to firewall to allow incoming and outgoing port and it did not work.

Comment: It might be helpful if you share the code about how to create and start windows service and the web.config file. This problem may occur because the Windows service is trying to start multiple copies of the WCF service host.